# ASP.NET Core : StaticWebAssets holding a lot of memory

Tags: css, asp.net-core, memory-management, bootstrap-5

I am investigating the memory usage of my application and I was suprised to see that a lot of memory
is held up by AspNetCore StaticWebAssets.

Please find the screenshot here:
[image]

Some relevant points :

1. I am using some static files in the application (around 1 MB total size). Those reside in the wwwroot/images folder.
2. I have added bootstrap , jquery in wwwroot for frontend layout.

My doubt is :
a) Why is the size of the static web asset so high?
b) Is there any way to restrict / reduce the size? I want to trim all unnecessary reference.

Based on the screenshot, the total size of the first 2 items is almost 50 MB. This seems wrong to me. Or is it an acceptable size for projects which uses Bootstrap and CSS (pretty normal stuff, nothing fancy). Looking for some guidance here.

Comment: I believe that will only happen when building/debugging... when published those files are just copied over to the wwwroot folder on the server.  You'll notice that your local build release/debug "bin" folder does not show the static files.  I think they're in a ".cache" file in the "obj" folder.  I believe that's what's making the "Inclusive Size" so large because the manifest is referencing objects in the .cache file.